# SVG icons dont show up correctly

Tags: html, css, image, svg, icons

```css
.footer-wrapper{
font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
display: flex;
padding: 2rem;
width: 90%;
margin: auto;
align-items: center;
min-height: 10vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-wrapper">
  <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="/icons/instagram(3).svg" alt=""></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="/icons/twitter(2).svg" alt=""><</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="/icons/linkedin(1).svg" alt=""></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I used the above code for the social media icons in the footer.But i dont know what why icons dont show up correctly its like either one of them appears and others dont and also shows weird characters like something similar to a less than sign.Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Don't have reputation points to post a snapshot :(

Comment: Altho there is a way I can show that wait...

Comment: You may need to give the li elements a width. Otherwise the svg elements may collapse to 0 if they don't hava a width

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/JchRIa2.png

Comment: do u mean i need to access li footer-wrapper and increase its width?

Comment: That pasteboard link will show up the snapshot

Comment: enxaneta thanks that worked but now the h5 inside it disappeared :/

Comment: I'm sorry to hear about the h5. Maybe you should to edit your question and show the h5 to in your code

Comment: Actually I accessed h5 of footer wrapper and increased its height and it worked I don't it's reason for collapsing tho and how good of a practice this is but it worked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u can take a snapshot it would be better.
Your line 3 has an extra "<" sign that's why it showed up

```
<div class="footer-wrapper">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="/icons/instagram(3).svg" alt=""></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="/icons/twitter(2).svg" alt=""></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="/icons/linkedin(1).svg" alt=""></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Using svg icons as  tag is totally wrong use icon generators like GRUNT compiler or webs for example Icomoon then put them inside  tag.!
 2.img src="/icons/twitter(2).svg" alt=""><
 you have extra < in you codes.
3.use font-size maybe it would work.!
4.be sure src is correct.
5.add width: 100% not 90% and height 100%